# Rename tag appstore to mac-appstore and ios-appstore

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Since Apple's Mac Appstore is coming in less than 90 days, should we think about renaming all [appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appstore) question to [ios-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-appstore), before all the question related to the Mac Appstore start to appear?

And in the process, create the [mac-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-appstore) tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appstore) to [ios-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-appstore) migrated. [mac-appstore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-appstore) hasn't been made yet.

Answer (score 3):

Please update the tag synonyms. I've had to fill in five captchas while trying to tag [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3572/1451) `app-store` and I would never have made it without knowing StackExchange in depth in the first place. The whole process was very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

on apple.com it says summer, not 90 days

Comment: Steve Jobs said 90 days from the keynote for the beta. They're already accepting submissions.